# What is the plane $x=z\cot\alpha \ (0<\alpha<\pi)$?

Tags: differential-geometry

This question is based on an exercise in do Carmo's *Differential Geometry*:

[image]

Here is my question:

> Why is $$x=z\cot\alpha,\quad 0<\alpha<\pi
> $$ a plane ?

I don't understand this parametrization. It seems that it means
$$
\begin{align}
x(z,\alpha)&=z\cot\alpha,\\
y(z,\alpha)&=?,\qquad \ \ \ \ \ \alpha\in(0,\pi),\ \ z\in{\Bbb R}\\
z(z,\alpha)&=z, 
\end{align}
$$
But this doesn't make sense to me since I don't see what is $y(z,\alpha)$.

Comment: I assume $\alpha$ is supposed to be a constant. This then gives the equation for a plane (i.e. there's one linear equation, $x+0y -\cot(\alpha)z = 0$ which is what defines a plane.)

Comment: Thanks to the comment and answer, I just found that this is kind of a dumb question. The underlined sentence could have been much clearer if the author puts it as "Let $P$  be the plane $x=z\cotα$  for *some* $α$  with $0<α<π$ " or uses the set notation 
$$P_α :=\{(x,y,z)∈R^3 ∣x=z\cotα\} $$
 for *some* $α∈(0,π)$ .

Comment: No worries. I agree that it's misleading. If you're trying to think about things as parameterised by open sets then it's easy to get confused!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $z=t$ then $x=t\cot \alpha$ and $y=s$, the the parametric equation of the plane is
$$r(t,s)=(t\cot \alpha,s,t)=t(\cot \alpha,0,1)+s(0,1,0)$$ for a fixed value of $\alpha, 0<\alpha< \pi$